# Clojure: Could not locate System/IO/File__init.class, System/IO/File.clj or System/IO/File.cljc on classpath

Tags: clojure

I am trying to run the following code that cuts a .csv file (can be thought of as plaintext) down to 100 lines:

```
(ns tst.demo.core
  (:require [clojure.java.io :as io] [System.IO.File])
  (:import [java.io File]))

(defn lines [n filename]
  (with-open [rdr (io/reader filename)]
    (doall (take n (line-seq rdr)))))

(defn spit-lines [^String filename a-seq]
  (->> a-seq
       (System.Linq.Enumerable/Cast (type-args System.String))
       (System.IO.File/WriteAllLines filename)))

(spit-lines(lines 100 "test_set_batch1.csv")))
```

Whenever I run this I get  the following error:

```
Syntax error (FileNotFoundException) compiling at (RemoveAfterLine100.clj:1:1).
Could not locate System/IO/File__init.class, System/IO/File.clj or System/IO/File.cljc on classpath.
```

I'm confused as to what's causing this error. I added System.IO.File to the :requires, so I thought it should work.

Comment: Are you using Clojure on the CLR, or the JVM? `[java.io File]` looks like it's JVM, but `[System.IO.File]` looks like it's CLR. You can't use both at the same time.

Comment: `System.Linq.Enumerable` is definitely CLR:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable?view=netcore-3.1    As @mange says, Clojure  is hosted on either the JVM or CLR (or Javascript).  It doesn't make sense to use interop for more than one at a time (i.e. whichever host you are on).

Answer (score 0):

As @mange and @Alan Thompson pointed out, my problem is that I was trying to run a script on both CLR and JVM.